# Operating on two ndarrays with same flexible type yields unexpected results

Tags: python, numpy

Consider following (minimal) example of numpy ndarray with flexible type:

```
import numpy as np
dt = np.dtype([('f1', np.uint8), ('f2', np.int8)])
# dtype([('f1', 'u1'), ('f2', 'i1')])
data1 = np.fromstring(b'\x00\x01', dtype=dt)
#  array([(0, 1)], 
#       dtype=[('f1', 'u1'), ('f2', 'i1')])
data2 = np.fromstring(b'\xE0\xE1', dtype=dt)
# array([(224, -31)], 
#       dtype=[('f1', 'u1'), ('f2', 'i1')])
```

What would be a most straightforward way to do elementwise operations on such arrays?

Common operations yields few unexpected results.

Subtracting:

```
>>> data2 - data1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Expected:

```
array([(224, -32)], 
      dtype=[('f1', 'u1'), ('f2', 'i1')])
```

Boolean operations:

```
>>> data2 > 1
True
```

Expected:

```
array([(True, False)], 
      dtype=[('f1', 'bool'), ('f2', 'bool')])
```

I know I can explicitly iterate over `dt.fields` (possibly recursively for nested flexible types), and do operations on individual homogenous ndarrays but is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: As a general rule you can't do this with structured arrays.  The elements of the array are defined by the compound dtype.  If `minus` isn't defined for that compound dtype you can't subtract one such array from the other.

Comment: Can I define minus operator for my custom created dtype?

Comment: It may be possible, but it won't be easy.  If you must, read up on defining custom `dtypes`.